# How do you migrate a database from SQL Server 2008 to MySQL?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sql-server-2008-r2, migration

I'm just getting into MySQL, so forgive me if this is a basic question. For my application I need to migrate my database **from SQL Server 2008 R2 to MySQL**.

**Is there any mechanism or technique or suggestion or tips or magic tricks   for migration?**

Comment: Hey shamim, I removed the last two lines from your question as I didn't see they added any information to it. Feel free to edit if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tools which are very efficient in migrating the data from one type of the database to other.

There are many types of tools some of them are freely available.I have used **Talend** which is very efficient in doing this.

**It is also freely available.**

Comment: @Shamim : you can download Talend Open Studio and start working if have any questions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the data is the easy part.  The T-SQL code all needs to be checked to ensure that you aren't using any SQL Server specific features like TOP, CTEs, SQL CLR, etc and that'll all need to be converted.  Even if there's a tool to convert it, you'll need to test everything to make sure that everything is still working the way that you want it to be working.